# AdMob error: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView"

Tags: android, admob, android-studio

So I'm on Android Studio v 0.3.6 and I'm having problems with Google Play Services. I was already using the Admob jar in my project but I had to update it so I tried to add them via the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). My project compiles fine however when I try to run an activity I get the following error:

```
Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.mre. example-1. apk
```

See the full [error output here](http://pastebin.com/HA5ty7Wa) Relevant portion of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    //compile project(':libraries:google-play-services_lib')
    //compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    ... 
}

android {
     compileSdkVersion 18
     buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'
     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

Here's my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"ex">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>
```

Here's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
...
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
            android:gravity="center" />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Over the past two days I have tried every variation of adding the GPS library to my project, to just the jar to both to none. At first I deleted the jar from my /libs and added the required lines to my build.gradle but that didn't work either. I thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package changed to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest and com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Change your import and your layouts

Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration) tutorial to migrate your apk.

Comment: Is it necessary to migrate to Goog Play Svcs for Admob?  What is the difference?

Comment: It's not mandatory (at least until now). You can check the differences [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

Comment: Migrating to Google Play Services for AdMob is mandary if you wish to update or release a new app after August 1st 2014 (reference: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android))

Comment: Link to tutorial is a 404

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forget to add `google_play_services_lib` to my project. I fixed that by adding this library... Hope it will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

Landed in similar problem while configuring firebase. Need to add play-services as dependency in app level gradle file -

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

Important part here is -

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

Post this sync your project and all required classes should be available.